# Using R for Introductory Statistics - Verzani Problem 8.6

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am trying to solve the Verzani problem 8.6 in his book, but I have no idea how to.

I have to use the confidence intervals to solve the problem.
Here is the picture of the problem:
[Problem 8.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2FW7.png)
**A student wishes to find the proportion of left-handed people at her college. She surveys 100 fellow students and finds that only 5 are left-handed.
If she computed a 95% confidence interval would it contain the value of
p = 1/10?**

I have tried to use the confidence interval formulas, I have already solved some of these problems using the confidence interval formula, but I don't know how to solve the last part - **would it contain the value of
p = 1/10?**

Formula I am using
[image: Formula I am using]

by using this formula, lower is $-0.1410372$ and upper is $0.2410372$.

If someone would help me get an answer so I can learn from it or guide me to an answer.

Thank you so much...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am so sorry, first time posting on this exchange, thank you for the feedback @JoséCarlosSantos , Is it okay now ? I edited the question.

Comment: Not really. Did you read the “please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem” part of my comment?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have added some thoughts about the solution, I am trying to exercise statistics for my classes that I am kinda lost in. Thank you so much for your guidence and help.

Comment: Did you find the confidence interval for the proportion, based on $5/100$ in the sample?

Comment: Yes, by using the formula that I added into the question , lower is -0.1410372 and upper is 0.2410372.

Comment: And now I dont know how to solve the last part of the problem **would it contain the value of p = 1/10?**

Comment: Don't tell me that I am that stupid and you just have to check if the value p is inside the lower and upper limit :D.

Comment: You do not seem to have applied your formula for the Wald confidence interval correctly.  Nor (since the book is about R) is it what you would get using `binom.test` (a Clopper-Pearson interval) or using `prop.test` (a Wilson interval with continuity correction).

Comment: @BruceET It might be more usual to use $\hat pi=0.05$ as that is what was suggested by the sample

Comment: @Henry. Googled around and found several sources claiming 10% is worldwide proportion of left handed people, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness). That's why I used it  at the end of my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the Wald CI is as follows:

$$\hat\pi \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{\hat\pi(1-\hat\pi)}{n}}.$$

So using *data,* you'd use $\hat\pi = 0.05, n = 100.$
This interval is $(0.0073, 0.0927)$ from the computation in R below. It is *centered* at the point estimate $\hat\pi=0.05$ from data, but it does **not** contain $\pi = 0.1.$

```
pi.hat = 5/100
CI.wald = pi.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(pi.hat*(1-pi.hat)/100)
CI.wald
[1] 0.007283575 0.092716425
```

*Notes:* (1) Because you are using R, you must be careful
*never* to name a variable as `pi` in R, where `pi` is
used for a 'reserved constant' $\pi = 3.14159\cdots .$
[It's OK to use variations such as `pi.hat` and `pi.est`.]

(2) The Wald interval depends of asymptotic arguments
and should be used only for samples that are at least moderately large (some use $n \ge 500$ as a rough rule).

The Agresi-Cooll CI is much the same in form as
the Wald CI, but more accurate for $n < 500,$ or so.
For data $x = 5, n = 100$ it computes to
$(0.019, 0.115),$ which **does** contain the value $\pi = 0.1.$

```
p.est = (5+2)/(100+4)
CI.agresti = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/104)
CI.agresti
[1] 0.01915363 0.11546176
```

Another very useful CI for binomial proportions
is the Jeffreys interval, which uses a beta
distribution. This interval computes to $(0.019,0.1061),$ which also contains the value $\pi = 0.1.$

```
CI.jeffreys = qbeta(c(.025,.975), 5.5, 95.5)
CI.jeffreys
[1] 0.01933181 0.10610007
```

Clopper-Pearson 95% CIs tend to be wider than other
styles in order to ensure at least 95% coverage probability in all cases.
This style of CI is provided along with the procedure `binom.test` in R. For your data this Ci is $(0.0164, 0.1128).$ It contains the value $\pi = 0.1.$

```
binom.test(5, 100)$conf.int
[1] 0.01643188 0.11283491
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

I mention these additional styles of binomial confidence intervals because the point of this exercise might be
to show that the Wald interval doesn't contain the
known value $1/10,$ while the some other styles of CIs do.

*Ref:* All of the styles of CIs illustrated above are discussed
in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) on binomial confidence intervals.

Comment: Nice summarization and explanation, thank you !!

Comment: Glad it got to you. Encountered this on Stat Stackexchenge. It seems to have bounced around a bit.